# Match the width of another div which uses width:auto; and then add x amount to it

Tags: jquery, css, width

Is there anyway I can make a div match the width of another div, when the other div uses width:auto; and is changed dynamically depending on the content. Then add an extra amount of pixels to the width.

For example...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yF4xL/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="filler"></div>
    <div id="filler"></div>
    <div id="filler"></div>
</div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#div1 {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    padding-right:10px;
}

#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    min-width:100px;
    top:150px;
    background-color:red;
}

#filler {
    position:relative;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
}
```

How can I make div2 match the width of div1 and then add 100px to it? So that no matter how many filler divs I put into div 1, div 2 will always be the same width +100?

Like...
(div2 width) = (div1 width) + 100

I suspect that Jquery will be involved somehow so I've added it to my tags.

Comment: Well, did you just try `$('#div2').width( $('#div1').width() + 100 )`, and then sticking that inside a resize event handler ?

Comment: When it changes dynamically, that's when you need to run the jQuery code for setting the width of the other element, as well as when the page first loads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
 $('#div2').width( $('#div1').outerWidth() + 100 )
```

the function outerWidth() include div borders.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe position the inner div absolutely in the outer div and set `left: 0` and `right: -100px` (implictly setting `width: auto`)?